# Can I use SSRS 2008 R2 with a SQL Server 2008 database?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have some databases on a SQL Server 2008 instance. I want to report on them so I installed SSRS 2008, which is obviously ancient. I know SSRS 2008 R2 uses Report Builder 3.0 though so I was blithly confident 2008 does too, but it turns out that SQL Server 2008 uses Report Builder 1.0 which is quite different.

I want to know if I can install SSRS 2008 R2 and hook it up to the SQL Server 2008 database, or will this simply not work.

I know the right answer is to upgrade all the things, but alas that's not possible at the moment.

Comment: I assume you want to be able to host the 2008R2 report databases (ReportServer and ReportServerTempDB) on your 2008 instance? I 'think' this is possible but can't be certain. How about installing Visual Studio Community Edition with SSDT. That supports SSRS projects going back to 2008. Then you can leave your setup as-is.

Comment: @Larnu yeah there's a schedule to upgrade but sadly this needs doing now and I can't bring the upgrade forwards. C'est la vie - thank you.

Comment: @AlanSchofield thanks but I specifically need the server so less technically minded colleagues can run the reports without my intervention, I think I'll just try it and see what happens!

Comment: Hi Dan. Users should really execute reports from the report manager interface (unless I misunderstood you). VS2017/ReportBuilder should be used to design and deploy the reports, unless you mean these users are building their own report of course...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, SSRS2008R2 documentation seems is not available anymore.

However, according to official docs of newer release: [Even SSRS 2014 can run on following instances](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/install/create-a-report-server-database-ssrs-configuration-manager?view=sql-server-2014):

- SQL Server 2014
- SQL Server 2012
- SQL Server 2008 R2
- **SQL Server 2008**
- SQL Server 2005

Therefore, assumption that SSRS 2008R2 with a **high probability** will run without problems on SQL 2008 data engine